# Do men with an African ethnic background have larger penises in comparison to men of European ethnic background? If so, why?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

Do men with an African ethnic background have, on average, a larger penis than their European counterparts?

Comment: That question is... not unusual. It's addressed on Wikipedia's page on human penis size (which, by the way, exists) of all things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_penis_size#Size_and_race

Comment: You might want to reformulate "black and white" men. This is a rather unscientific wording. Also, I find the title of your question rather amusing :) .. This is a perfectly legitimate, biological question just say what you would like to know and try not to step into the pitfalls of everyday language which unfortunately very often has a "racial/racist" bias. There is no shame in the human anatomy.

Comment: I think that 4 down votes (5 actually as there was an up vote) is a bit overreacting. Among the 4 close votes, only one states that because the post shows lack of effort (via the 'homework question' reason for closing) and 3 said the post is opinion based. I don't thin the post is opinion based. I agree that given the gigantic genetic diversity present in Africa, the category African ethnicities might be unclear though.

Comment: I am not a student. I would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [Oarkwe and Ebuh 2007](http://www.ajol.info/index.php/tjmr/article/view/30465)

> The mean full-stretch penile length of the Nigerian Blacks was 13.37cm and the mean flaccid length was 9.36cm. Similar studies reported full-stretch penile lengths of 12.50cm in Italians, 12.18cm in Greeks, 9.6cm in Koreans, 13cm in British Caucasians, and 12.45cm in the American Caucasians. The penile length for Nigerian Blacks was longer than those of the other races, but the differences were only statistically different in comparison with the Koreans.